# Change Language and Regional settings on Windows

Tags: windows, powershell

I never tried doing this, but I think it is possible. I need a executable file, 
or a script, that can automatically change Default Windows Format and Digital symbol.

I need it so that I can one click change the default Region on many PCs.
I made a shortcut for opening intl.cpl:
`C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL intl.cpl,,0`

But I want it all to be automatic:

- Change format to:
  [Serbian (Latin, Serbia)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRPCQ.png)
- Change Decimal and grouping Symbol to:["." and "," respectively](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKJfY.png)
- And Change RegionSetings to:[Serbian (Latin, Serbia)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cstTy.png)

I found [this PowerShell Script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-change-the-System-82479048) but I don't know how to make all changes that I want.

Comment: As an aside: You can invoke `*.cpl` files directly (both in `cmd` and PowerShell), so just `intl.cpl` by itself should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the three commands I use for changing Windows 10 to UK English (`en-GB` / `242`), I had a look for the Serbian values and found these from a bit of google-fu:

- `sr-Latn-RS` language (from [Windows table of Language IDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/a9eac961-e77d-41a6-90a5-ce1a8b0cdb9c))
- `271` for GeoId (from [table-of-geographical-locations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/intl/table-of-geographical-locations))

Hopefully those are the correct values for your language/location.

I can't test these commands as I don't have a VM to hand and don't want to change the language on my own system.

```
Set-WinSystemLocale -SystemLocale sr-Latn-RS
Set-WinHomeLocation -GeoId 271
Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList (New-WinUserLanguageList -Language sr-Latn-RS) -Force
```

---

**EDIT:**

OP found the settings for the other configuration changes:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\International" -Name sDecimal -Value "."
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\International" -Name sThousand -Value ","
```